# Matlab - Locating file on a path that's inside package

Tags: matlab

Been trying (unsucessfully) to use 'which' to locate a .m file inside a package. For example, calling "which('Company.m')", when Company.m is inside a +Contents folder.

So if my current folder is C:\Users\Documents\Contents (path added to Matlab paths), "which('Company.m')" indicates no file found, but if my current folder is C:\Users***\Documents\Contents\ +Contents, then it will know the location.

Why is this? I thought that the 'which' command recursively searches through all subdirectories? Is there anyway to retrieve the path name of 'Company.m' without having to specifically source into that folder?

Comment: Is there a reason to not `Add to Path->Selected Folder *and Subfolders*` so the function can be found on the path? At that point, `which` will do what you want.

Comment: You can't add packages to the path.

Comment: Ah... in that case, can you do `which('+Contents/Company.m')`? Or do you not know ahead of time what package the function you're looking for is in?

Comment: I do not necessarily know if it is in a package or not (and if it is, which one it is in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be:

```
which Contents.Company
```

If you dont know beforehand in which package it resides (or if its even in one), you could import them all:

```
import Contents.*
import OtherPackage.*
which -all Company
```

If you are still not satisfied, you could get a list of all top-level packages available, and search the methods they expose for the function you want:

```
 %# warning: this might take more than a few seconds
 p = meta.package.getAllPackages;
 b = cellfun(@(pkg) ismember('Company',{pkg.FunctionList.Name}), p);
 idx = find(b, 1, 'first');
 p{idx}.Name
```